# Calling API Showing Parameter missing error in JMeter

Tags: parameters, jmeter

[When calling API then parameter missing error showing. what can I do? please give me a solution. Thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERb4b.png)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot "give you a solution" without seeing your request details and what does your API expect.

Double check that your request payload contains `delivery_name` parameter and if it does ensure that you have [`Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema) in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)